# Huffman coding and priority queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, priority-queue, huffman-code

I had an assignment today and I'm really struggling trying to find a solution.
"Using a Binary-Search-Tree based priority queue, implement Huffman Coding [...]".
So, basically, I have to write my own priority queue based on a Binary Search Tree.
I managed to get a working BST and so on, but I've been really smashing my head against every wall In my room for the last two-tree days for the second part.
And that's Huffman's fault (Just kidding, I know I'm kinda stupid).
In Huffman Algorithm, we create a priority queue, fill it with our N starting elements, then we pop() the 2 nodes with minimum frequences, create a new node whose frequence is the sum of the previously popped elements and push() that node into the priority queue and reiterate[...].
To make my BST into a priority queue, I added  one member and two methods: `min`,`getMin()` and `extractMin()`.
`min` is a pointer to the node whose value is the lowest in the tree.
`getMin()` is a method that starts from a given node, and looks for the minimum value in its left subtree.
Please, note that everytime a node gets removed or  a new node inserted, it calls an update of the `min` variable of the tree (a new inserted node could have a lower value than the previous `min`, so `min`gets updated, and the node pointer by `min` could be removed, so`min` gets updated).
`extractMin()` is basically a wrapper for `pQueue.remove(pQueue.getMin())`.
The thing is this: after popping the two elements with lowest frequency, and creating the new node, inserting it in the tree causes a `min` update. Since the `left` and `right` members of the new inserted node have a lower frequence than the inserted note itself, the `min` variable is set to one of those two members. I am struggling to find a solution to this. I don't want code or lines, I just want some ideas because I really ran out of patience and intelligence.
Following, my BST class and a snippet of the Huffman code I wrote. Please, be kind, I'm new to coding.

```
   template <class T>
class BST
{
    private:

        void setRoot(bstNode<T>* nd){this->root=nd;}
        bool isEmpty()const{if (this->getRoot()==nullptr) return true; else return false;}
    protected:
        bstNode<T>* root;
        bstNode<T>* min;
    public:
        BST(void){this->root=nullptr;this->min=nullptr;}
        BST(bstNode<T>* rt){this->root=rt;}
        ~BST(void){this->root=nullptr;};
        void inorder(bstNode<T>*) const;
        void insert(bstNode<T>*);
        bool remove(bstNode<T>*);
        void extractMin();
        bstNode<T>* getRoot()const {return this->root;} 
        bstNode<T>* getMin(bstNode<T>*)const; 
        bstNode<T>* getMin()const {return this->min;} //simply returns a pointer to the minimum
        void setMin(bstNode<T>* nd){this->min=nd;}
};

template <class T>
void BST<T>::extractMin()
{
    if (this->getMin()!=nullptr)
        this->remove(this->getMin());
    else return;
}


template <class T>
void BST<T>::insert(bstNode<T>* nd)
{
    if (this->isEmpty()==true)
    {
        this->setRoot(nd);
        this->setMin(nd);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        bstNode<T>* up=nullptr;
        bstNode<T>* actual=this->getRoot();

    while (actual!=nullptr)
    {
        up=actual;
        if(nd->getValue()<=actual->getValue())
            actual=actual->getLeft();
        else actual=actual->getRight();
    }
    nd->setParent(up);
    if (nd->getValue()<=up->getValue())
        up->setLeft(nd);
    else up->setRight(nd);
}
if (nd->getValue()<=this->getMin()->getValue())
    this->setMin(nd);
}

template <class T>
bool BST<T>::remove(bstNode<T>* nd)
{

    if (nd==this->getMin())
        this->setMin(nullptr);
    if (nd==this->getRoot() && nd->getRight()==nullptr && nd->getLeft()==nullptr)
    {
        this->setRoot(nullptr);
        return true;
    }
    if (nd==this->getRoot() && nd->getRight()!=nullptr)
        this->setRoot(nd->getRight());
    else if( nd==this->getRoot() && nd->getLeft()!=nullptr)
        this->setRoot(nd->getLeft());
    bstNode<T>* Root=this->getRoot();
    bstNode<T>* temp, *temp2;;
    if (nd->getLeft()==nullptr)
        this->swapTree(Root,nd,nd->getRight());
    else if (nd->getRight()==nullptr)
        this->swapTree(Root,nd,nd->getLeft());
    else 
    {
        temp=this->getMin(nd->getRight());
        if (temp->getParent()!=nd)
        {
            this->swapTree(Root,temp,temp->getRight());
            temp->setRight(nd->getRight());
            temp2=temp->getRight();
            temp2->setParent(temp);
        }
        this->swapTree(Root,nd,temp);
        temp->setLeft(nd->getLeft());
        temp2=temp->getLeft();
        temp2->setParent(temp);
    }
    this->setMin(this->getMin(this->getRoot()));
    return true;
}
template <class T>
bstNode<T>* BST<T>::getMin(bstNode<T>* nd)const //find and return the minimum of the tree whose root is nd
{
    while (nd->getLeft()!=nullptr)
        nd=nd->getLeft();
    return nd;
}
```

and here's the Huffman part:

```
template <class T>
class Encoder
{
    private:
        std::vector <myTuple> *alphabet; //vector of tuples     <fequency,character, isInternal>
        void createPqueue();
        void createAlphabet();
        void encode();
        void showHuff(bstNode<T>*, string);
        BST<T> *hTree;
    public:
        Encoder(){createAlphabet();createPqueue();};
        ~Encoder(){};
        std::vector <myTuple> * getAlphabet()const{return this-    >alphabet;}
        BST<T> *getPqueue()const{return this->hTree;}
        void askWhat();
};

template <class T>
void Encoder<T>::createPqueue()
{
    this->hTree=new BST<myTuple>();
    if (this->hTree==nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"Error allocating Red-Black Tree, now exiting..."<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}



for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->getAlphabet()->size(); ++i)
{
    bstNode<myTuple>* temp;
    temp=new bstNode<myTuple>(this->getAlphabet()->at(i));
    if (temp!=nullptr)
        this->getPqueue()->insert(temp); //fill the priority Queue with  <int frequency, char character, bool is_internal> Nodes. I still have to remove tuples since they are not necessary anymore.
    else
         exit(-1);
}
bstNode<myTuple> *left, *right, *top;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i< u_int(this->getAlphabet()->size())-2;i++)
{
    left=this->getPqueue()->getMin();
    this->getPqueue()->extractMin();
    right=this->getPqueue()->getMin();
    this->getPqueue()->extractMin();
    myTuple temp ((get<0>( left->getValue() ) + get<0>( right->getValue() )),'\0',true);
    top=new bstNode<myTuple>(temp);
    if (top==nullptr)
    {
        cout <<"Can't allocate top, now exiting..."<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    top->setLeft(left);
    top->setRight(right);
    this->getPqueue()->insert(top);
}
```

I've been using the `bool` value in tuples to distinguish between internal and external nodes, but with no success.
Thank you in advance and I'm really sorry if I've been messy, my clearness equals my state of mind as of now. Thank you.

Comment: This is very inefficient approach as you have to update the pointer,Is it neceassary to use `BST` as MinPQ because MinPQ is based on heap datastructure which is not fully sorted but as you remove anything from it , it will automatically rebalance and you don't need a pointer for minimum element because it is always in the root.

Comment: Having just a glance at your code, don't you mix up huffman tree with BST? I mean, you should have a distinct left/right pointer for the BST, and for the huffman as well (provided that you want to create the huffman tree itself, not just huffman codes). Btw, no one implements priority queue with BST. Heap is more efficient (both space/time) and much simpler as well. I wonder, why you have to use BST for this...

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: Priority queue is not necessarily based on the heap data structure. Binary heap is one particularly useful *implementation* of the priority queue data structure, but there are many other possible implementations. The OP's assignment clearly states, "Use a Binary Search Tree based priority queue ..."

Comment: @JimMischel i did not say that the only possible implementation of MinPQ is based on Heap! but i said meant thereby efficient implementation.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: Then I misinterpreted your comment. My apologies.

Comment: You just don't need the `min` pointer at all.  getMin() should start at the root and go left as far as possible.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the instructions regarding binary tree & priority queue. A standard implementation fills a priority queue with binary tree leaf nodes. It then assembles new subtrees by popping two elements, making the popped elements children of a new binary tree node, and pushing the result back onto the priority queue. Repeat until the priority queue has one element. The sole element in your priority queue now points to the root of your binary tree Huffman code representation.  I don't think you're being asked to implement a priority queue AS a binary tree...

Comment: Hello everybody and thank you.
@Matt Timmermans: I know that I don't need it, I've been using it for debugging purposes, and since MinPQ usually have a pointer to the "top" element, `min` acts like that, pointing to the next item to be removed. @Geza: I can't see your point. I mean, I've been browsing everywhere, and every algorithm that I've seen uses the same PQ for popping the two lowest nodes and inserting the new created node. Thank you everybody for your efforts, by the way. The question is: can you think of a solution to distinguish between internal and external nodes?

Comment: @pjs: the assignment states "the algorithm must use a PQ, realized via a BST". I can't clear my mind enough on this. Not yet, at least...

Comment: It seems (but maybe I'm wrong), that you use left/right for two purposes: BST and huffman tree. But I think, these have to be distinct. A left node of a node could differ in the BST, and in the huffman-tree.

Comment: So, you set left/right for a node for huffman (at the bottom of your code, `top->setLeft(left)`), but when you add it to the BST, they will be overwritten.

Comment: @geza: True: I use the same `left` - `right` pointer for different purposes. Should I use two different members `bstNode<T>* ` `left` and `right`, and maybe `hufftree<T>*` `leftHuff` and `rightHuff` ? Is this what you mean?

Comment: All I say is that you need to have separate pointers for BST and huffman. The exact implementation is up to you :) There's a lot to be told about these kind of stuff (check out intrusive/non-intrusive containers), it doesn't fit into a comment.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I think it's now up to me to solve this. Thank you, again.